# What causes merge conflicts in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, merge

I constantly run into conflicts when I attempt to merge files. When I am resolving the conflicts, the "conflicts" seem to be just the changes in the new version (source file). Shouldn't TSF "know" this and just merge the file without flagging it as a conflict? Is there a threshold on the number of changes a file can contain before it raises a merge conflict? Other members of the dev team do not have this issue, or not nearly as often as me.

One possible unique circumstance is we have a dev TFS server and a production server. I am getting these conflicts when merging from dev to production. But again, no one else experiences this issue.

We are running TFS 2010.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the version you're using?  (There is not a Team Foundation Server 2011.)  The defaults changed in 2012 to automerge changes by default.

Comment: It's Team Foundation Server 2010.

Comment: Having a dev and prod TFS server and merging between them is really dysfunctional. You should have a single TFS server for all code.

Comment: How are you resolving conflicts? Using tf resolve command? If yes, you can use the /auto:AutoMerge parameter

Comment: @HamidShahid I'm not worried about resolving the conflict. I'm concerned about why there's a conflict in the first place. Some of the changes with which I encounter a conflict are trivial. They shouldn't be causing a conflict.